# How can I attach a 3.5" mounting plate to a 2.75" round electrical box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, drywall

I have an IKEA Ostana wall light with a 3.5" wall plate that I'm trying to attach to a electrical box in the wall with only two screw holes 2.75" apart. I've looked around but can't seem to find a simple way to get these to fit; even if I had a metal adapter plate with screw holes in the proper spots, the screws from the Ostana mounting plate go right about where the drywall ends in the wall. What should I be looking for?

I don't have the tools (power drill, work bench, clamps, etc) right now to machine holes into the Ostana wall plate, which would be an okay option except then I couldn't turn the light in certain orientations.

[image: Photo]

Comment: Ok, some further research indicates I need a ["universal crossbar"](https://www.amazon.com/Westinghouse-Lighting-70111-Adjustable-Purpose/dp/B000BO4HN6) or a ["spider plate"](https://www.amazon.com/L-H-Dottie-SP34-Capacity-20-Pack/dp/B00BV2ULMS). I guess in this case I would need machine screws to stick out of the wall through the crossbar, maybe with a nut, to stabilize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the universal crossbar and drill (or punch) holes through the drywall where the mounting screws for the fixture will land. The canopy that came with the fixture should cover the whole area.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy =) I ended up trying to use one of these, but couldn't get it to work because after all the screws were in, the light was no longer flush with the wall. In the end, I got a small drill and simply drilled holes where I needed them. It was much easier than I had expected!